# Nodejs/Socket - Add/Remove User From Room

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets

I am having trouble adding users to a room list, I can manage to do it on a global level (every user connected), but adding and removing users on a room basis, I just can't seem to grasp.

I have added a new var called

> roomUsers

app.js

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// usernames which are currently connected to the chat
var usernames = {};

// usernames which are currently connected to the chat
var roomUsers = {};

// rooms which are currently available in chat
var rooms = ['room1','room2','room3'];

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    
    // when the client emits 'adduser', this listens and executes
    socket.on('adduser', function(username){
        // store the username in the socket session for this client
        socket.username = username;
        // store the room name in the socket session for this client
        socket.room = 'room1';
        // add the client's username to the global list
        usernames[username] = username;
        // send client to room 1
        socket.join('room1');
        // echo to client they've connected
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected to room1');
        // echo to room 1 that a person has connected to their room
        socket.broadcast.to('room1').emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', username + ' has connected to this room');
        socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, 'room1');
        // update the list of users in chat,client side
        io.sockets.emit('updateUsers', usernames);
        //
        //io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('updateUsers', usernames);
    });
    
    // when the client emits 'sendchat', this listens and executes
    socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
        // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
        io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
    });
    
    socket.on('switchRoom', function(newroom){
        socket.leave(socket.room);
        socket.join(newroom);
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected to '+ newroom);
        // sent message to OLD room
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username+' has left this room');
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        // update socket session room title
        socket.room = newroom;
        socket.broadcast.to(newroom).emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username+' has joined this room');
        socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, newroom);
        io.sockets.emit('updateUsers', usernames);

    });
    

    // when the user disconnects.. perform this
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // remove the username from global usernames list
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        // update list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateUsers', usernames);
        // echo globally that this client has left
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username + ' has disconnected');
        socket.leave(socket.room);
    });
});
```

Is there any advice on where I am going wrong with io.sockets.emit('updateUsers', usernames); and delete usernames[socket.username]; (obviously I need to change that to roomUsers)

frontend.js

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

    // on connection to server, ask for user's name with an anonymous callback
    socket.on('connect', function(){
        // call the server-side function 'adduser' and send one parameter (value of prompt)
        socket.emit('adduser', prompt("What's your name?"));
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updatechat', this updates the chat body
    socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
        $('#conversation').append('<b>'+username + '></b> ' + data + '<br>');
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updateusers', this updates the username list
  socket.on('updateUsers', function(data) {
    $('#users').empty();
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      $('#users').append('<div>' + key + '</div>');
    });
  });



    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updaterooms', this updates the room the client is in
    socket.on('updaterooms', function(rooms, current_room) {
        $('#rooms').empty();
        $.each(rooms, function(key, value) {
            if(value == current_room){
                $('#rooms').append('<div>' + value + '</div>');
            }
            else {
                $('#rooms').append('<div><a href="#" onclick="switchRoom(\''+value+'\')">' + value + '</a></div>');
            }
        });
    });

    function switchRoom(room){
        socket.emit('switchRoom', room);
    }
    
    // on load of page
    $(function(){
        // when the client clicks SEND
        $('#datasend').click( function() {
            var message = $('#data').val();
            $('#data').val('');
            // tell server to execute 'sendchat' and send along one parameter
            socket.emit('sendchat', message);
        });

        // when the client hits ENTER on their keyboard
        $('#data').keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                $(this).blur();
                $('#datasend').focus().click();
            }
        });
    });
```

index.html

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8888/chat/js/frontend.js"></script>
<div style="float:left;width:100px;border-right:1px solid black;height:300px;padding:10px;overflow:scroll-y;">
    <b>ROOMS</b>
    <div id="rooms"></div>
</div>
<div style="float:left;width:100px;border-right:1px solid black;height:300px;padding:10px;overflow:scroll-y;">
  <b>USERS</b>
  <div id="users"></div>
</div>
<div style="float:left;width:300px;height:250px;overflow:scroll-y;padding:10px;">
    <div id="conversation"></div>
    <input id="data" style="width:200px;" />
    <input type="button" id="datasend" value="send" />
</div>
```

Comment: Sockets can connect to multiple rooms. When a socket disconnects, it automatically leaves all rooms, so you don't need to specify `socket.leave()` in `disconnect`.

Comment: Why are you removing the username in `switchRoom`?

Comment: because it has 3 rooms, i want it so if your in room1, and you click room2, it removes username from room1 and then adds to room2

Comment: How are you specifying a room to a username? You are writing: `usernames[username] = username;`. Maybe you want `usernames` to be an array?

Comment: I have added my frontend.js i get it from adduser

Comment: Still doesn't answer my question. How do you know username `x` in `usernames` is in `roomX`? And you just delete the username from `usernames` and never re-add it in `switchRoom`. It's basically the same thing as `disconnect`. I don't understand why `usernames` is an object, you're basically using it like an array.

Comment: Yeh, thats kind of my point - i don't know how to specify a username to the room. At the moment, it's just going in as a combined list of connected users to the chat server.

Comment: Then you want usernames to look something like: `var usernames = { room1: [], room2: [], room3: [] };` You should add a username like: `usernames[roomName].push(username);` and send `usernames[roomName]` in the `updateUsers` emit. In `switchRooms`, before you add the username, you should delete it from the previous room like: `var userIndex = usernames[oldRoom].indexOf(username); if (userIndex !== -1) { usernames[oldRoom].splice(userIndex, 1); } else { throw "username doesn't exist in old room."; }`. Don't forget to delete the username in `disconnect`. Also don't forget to update your client.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I shall work on it :)

Comment: Socket.io isnt  the smartest chat solution because the data is volatile and also is very hard to maintain users,its only nice for some kind of public chat where we dont need to maintain users.

Answer (score 2):

You should define add/remove functions inside users.js under utils folder and then import it to the app.js.

users.js

```
let users = [];

const addUser = ({ id, username, room }) => {
  // Clean the data
  username = username.trim().toLowerCase();
  room = room.trim().toLowerCase();

  // always validate the data
  if (!username || !room) {
    return {
      error: "Username and room are required!"
    };
  }

  // Check for existing user
  const userExist = users.find(user => {
    return user.room === room && user.username === username;
  });

  // Validate username
  if (userExist) {
    return {
      error: "Username is in use!"
    };
  }

  // Store user
  const user = { id, username, room };
  users.push(user);
  return { user };
};

const removeUser = id => {
  const index = users.findIndex(user => {
    user.id === id;
  });
  if (index !== 1) {
  //splice method returns the removed the user
    return users.splice(index, 1);
  }
};
module.exports = { addUser, removeUser};
```

Users are added, when they submitted the login form and joined the room. And we need removedUser to send disconnected users who are in particular room.

app.js

```
const { addUser, removeUser} = require("./utils/users");
//a simple utility function that send text and date
const { sendMessage } = require("./utils/messages");

io.on("connection", socket => {
  //once user submitted the form, server receives the username and room info. data={username,room}
  socket.on("join", (data, callback) => {
  //if you check addUser function it either returns error or user
    const { error, user } = addUser({ id: socket.id, ...data });

    if (error) {
      return callback(error);
    }
    //if there is no error, user joins the room
    socket.join(user.room);
    //send this generated message to the connected users
    socket.emit("message", sendMessage("Admin", "Welcome!"));
    //user broadcast to send info all users in the room but the last joined
    socket.broadcast
      .to(user.room)
      .emit(
        "message",
        sendMessage("Admin", `${user.username} has joined!`)
      );

    callback();
  });

socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    //socket.id is generated by socket upon connection
    const user = removeUser(socket.id);
    if (user) {
      io.to(user.room).emit(
        "message",
        sendMessage("Admin", `${user.name} has left`)
      );
    }
  });
```

/utils/messages.js

```
const generateMessage = function(username, text) {
  return {
    username,
    text,
    created: new Date().getTime()
  };
};
module.exports = { generateMessage };
```